# latest sonar doesn't display c# results only javascript

Tags: c#, sonarqube

I use latest jenkins and latest sonar (fresh install). When I view the dashboard for my project I see the results (bugs, etc) only for javascript and css, but not C#. Anyone can tell me what could be the problem ?

When the analysis is run I can see for a while the c# results but by the time the analysis is finished I only see the javascript results.

Comment: You need to provide more information about how your Jenkins is setup to run Sonar.

Comment: Check the [sonarqube doc](https://docs.sonarqube.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=1441900), it refers to a c# plugin you could be missing.

Comment: In jenkins I run Sonnar Scanner for MSBuild latest version. It is automatically handled by jenkins.

Comment: Sonar Qube has the c# plugin, of course.

Comment: Any logs? How does your build configuration looks like? There is not enough information in here to help you.